# R: Conditionally subsetting rows

Tags: r

I have a need to subset data by rows based on a "Flag" variable.  That is, in the example below, if flag == 1 followed by three or whatever 0s, then summarize M1 and M2 for the three rows where flag == 0. I expect that within G1 + G2 that the number of such events will vary.  For each, a summary is needed.

Can such subsetting and summarizing be completed by functions such as aggregate or it's variants or must this be coded with loops, explicitly indexing each element?  Any hints would be most appreciate.

```
G1  G2  G3  Flag M1 M2
10  1   0   0   0   5336.682
10  1   0   1   1   1871.782
10  1   0   0   0   3330.898
10  1   0   0   0   763.134
10  1   0   0   1   1183.485
10  1   0   0   1   385.664
10  1   0   0   1   372.036
10  1   0   1   1   329.601
10  1   1   1   0   281.965
10  1   1   0   0   377.866
10  1   1   0   0   328.342
10  1   1   0   0   512.528
10  1   1   1   0   777.216
10  1   1   0   0   409.559
10  1   1   1   0   417.606
10  1   1   1   0   673.728
10  1   1   0   0   1090.082
10  1   1   0   0   345.481
10  1   1   0   0   329.294
10  2   ... ... ... ... 
11  1   ... ... ... ... 
... ... ... ... ... ...
11  2   ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: So the group stays the same until you hit a new Flag==1, and then it's the next group?

Comment: G2 is nested within G1.  G2 is composed of two levels, 1 and 2.  I hope to locate all instances of the constraints (Flag == 1 followed by three or whatever Flag == 0), then generate summary stats (e.g., mean) for the two variables of interest, M1 & M2.  So, in this example summary stats would be performed on the three lines after the flag.  The first output be   generated from  M1[0, 0, 1] and M2[3330.898, 763.134, 1183.484]. Next, for M1[0,0,0] and M2[377.866, 328.342, 512.528]. The next flag == 1 doesn't satisfy the constraints.  All of these would be grouped with G1[10], G2[1].

Answer (score 2):

You can use data.table. First, put your data into a dataframe called 'df'. Then, run

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, group := cumsum(Flag)]
dt[, list(M1 = sum(M1[-1]), M2 = sum(M2[-1])), by = "group"]
```

You didn't specify which summary you need to sun, so we're just summing M1 and M2.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll explore but am not certain how the constraints are to being met.  I've further clarified above.

Comment: Because the "flags" are randomly assigned, some "groups" can be very short - length = 1.  As a consequence, it seems that it's not possible to calculate M2 = M2[2] + M2[3] + M2[4] to retrieve the sum of the 3 measurements, independent of group, immediately after flag == 1.